# Issue in converting C++ const char[] or std::string to Golang GoString

Tags: c++, go

In order to be able to call this golang function from a C++ code :

`basic.go` :

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    //"fmt"
    "github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go"
)

var lan lingua.Language

//var lan int

//export Langdetectfunct
func Langdetectfunct(text string) int { // text has to be GoString: https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go/blob/main/detector.go#L48

    detector := lingua.NewLanguageDetectorBuilder().
        FromAllLanguages().
        Build()

    if language, exists := detector.DetectLanguageOf(text); exists {
        lan = language
    }
    lan = lingua.English

    return int(lan)

}

func main() {
    // https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-go/blob/main/language.go 

    //res := Langdetectfunct("Languages are awesome");
    //fmt.Println(res)
}
```

I've built it in `c-shared` buildmode:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ go build -o basic.so -buildmode=c-shared basic.go
```

I imported the resulting `h` file into `basic1.cpp` file,
and tried to call the function from this cpp file

```
#include "basic.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std:: text = "Languages are awesome";
    int res = Langdetectfunct(text);
    std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile the C++ code specifying the shared object library I get this error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ g++ -std=c17 -o basic basic1.cpp ./basic.so 
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-std=c17’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
basic1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
basic1.cpp:5:21: error: conversion from ‘const char [22]’ to non-scalar type ‘GoString’ {aka ‘_GoString_’} requested
    5 |     GoString text = "Languages are awesome";
```

If I set text as std::string:

```
#include "basic.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string text = "Languages are awesome";
    int res = Langdetectfunct(text);
    std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
}
```

I get this other related error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ g++ -std=c17 -o basic basic1.cpp ./basic.so 
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-std=c17’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
basic1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
basic1.cpp:6:31: error: could not convert ‘text’ from ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘GoString’ {aka ‘_GoString_’}
    6 |     int res = Langdetectfunct(text);
      |                               ^~~~
      |                               |
      |                               std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
```

Update 1)

With `basic1.cpp` :

```
#include "basic.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    GoString text = "Languages are awesome";
    int res = Langdetectfunct(text);
    std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
}
```

Just compiling without any flags:

```
raphy@raohy:~/go-lang-detect$ g++ -o basic basic1.cpp ./basic.so 
basic1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
basic1.cpp:5:21: error: conversion from ‘const char [22]’ to non- 
scalar type ‘GoString’ {aka ‘_GoString_’} requested
   5 |     GoString text = "Languages are awesome";
```

So... how to correctly convert std::string or const char[] to GoString and viceversa?

Comment: That first (unrelelated to your issue) error message is pointing out a bad compiler flag. `-std=c++17` might be what you want instead. It would at least reduce some noise on the console.

Comment: @sweenish Thank you for helping. I updated my post above with Update 1) where I compiled without any flags

Comment: according to the [cgo documentation](https://go.dev/wiki/cgo) " Go strings are the combination of a length and a pointer to the first character in the string. C strings are just the pointer to the first character".  Go provides functions to convert from one to the other through `C.Cstring`, `C.GoString`, etc but keep in mind that `C` strings are not garbage collected.

Comment: @Claises Thanks to your suggestion, I solved the problem

Comment: @Claies If the C strings are not garbage collected, what problem could this cause?

Comment: Memory leak. Which can result in your program consuming resources until the whole system gets bogged down if left un-checked.

Comment: @sweenish In `C++` : `int res = Langdetectfunct(const_cast<char *>(text))` --> and then in `Golang` :  `func Langdetectfunct(text *C.char) int { textS := C.GoString(text); language, _ := detector.DetectLanguageOf(textS); return int(language)}` . Can `textS:=C.GoString(text)` cause memory leak?

Comment: I may have spoken hastily because the interop is not something I’m familiar with. But garbage collection in other languages does not exist in C++. It is on the dev to ensure memory is freed when an object’s lifetime ends. There are mechanisms for automating this in the language but C-strings don’t use them by default. If those strings are `new`ed into existence they have to be `delete[]`ed at some point. By you. Because there is no garbage collection. C++ is not an easy language, and it’s far easier to screw up than write correct code. The trade-off is control.